# How to access "Form Data" from Google dev tools using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome-devtools

I want to access the "professional_degree" from "Form Data" in Google dev tools under the 'Headers' section using PHP. Does anyone know how this can be achieved? See the screen show below.

[image]

Comment: [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) or [Dealing with Forms](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: Looks like `data` contains an URL-encoded query string format itself - so after accessing that parameter via $_GET, you will have to parse the value, using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: @CBroe - would you be able to give me an example please on how I would do this?

Comment: The manual has an example on how to use the function I mentioned, and the first comment already contained links where you can read up on how to access your `data` parameter. What more do you need?

Comment: @CBroe I can't use the $_GET as this is done via a AJAX call, so I am not able to retrieve the parameter in the URL as there isn't any.

Comment: You need to do it in the place where you are processing that AJAX request then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the $_GET or $_POST based on the http method used, but it is not clear from the question. Or you can use $_REQUEST which contains both variables. Then parse the value of the `data` field and select the `professional_degree`:

```
$data = $_REQUEST['data'];
parse_str($data, $result);
$professional_degree = $result['professional_degree'];
```